# Jupyter NoteBook Slide - Dataframe format and size

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, slideshow

For a "code presenting session", I would like to transform my Jupyter NoteBook to slides. It works pretty well actually but for the Dataframe display.

I have currently this display in my notebook:

[image]

and I get that on the Slide:

[image]

Why? Is it possible to get the same rendering on both notebook/slides?

Thanks

Comment: What solution are you using to convert the output to slides?

Comment: It’s been a long time ago, I think slideshow based on the tags

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible. One way to achieve this is to use the `pandas` library's `Styling` feature to customize the style of the DataFrame.

for example if you have this dataframe:

```
data = {'Name': ['Hana', 'Mohsen', 'Bob'],
        'Age': [25, 30, 21],
        'Salary': [1500, 2000, 3000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

you can use this :

```
styled_df = df.style \
    .set_properties(**{'background-color': 'white',
                        'color': 'black',
                        'border-color': 'black'}) \
    .set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th',
                        'props': [('border', '1px solid black')]}])
```

This code sets the background color, font color, and border color of the DataFrame, and adds a border to the table headers. You can customize the style further by adding more properties or styles to the `set_properties` and `set_table_styles` methods.

To display the styled DataFrame in Jupyter Notebook and slides, you can simply run this code in both environments. The styled DataFrame will be displayed with the same style in both environments.

if you want to include the styling code in the slides, you may need to convert the DataFrame to an image using the `DataFrame.to_html` and `IPython.display.HTML` functions.

for example you can use this code in order to convert DataFrame to an image:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
# convert the DataFrame to an HTML table
html_table = df.to_html()
# display the HTML table as an image
HTML(html_table)
```

The resulting HTML table is stored as a string in the html_table variable.
Next, the HTML function from the IPython.display module is used to display the HTML table as an image in the Jupyter Notebook output. This will display the DataFrame as a table with the **default styling**.
You can customize the styling of the HTML table by passing **CSS** properties to the style argument of the to_html method. For example:

```
html_table = df.to_html(style={'background-color': 'lightgray',
                                'border': '1px solid black',
                                'padding': '5px'})
```

this will sets the background color, border, and padding of the HTML table. You can customize the styling further by adding more CSS properties to the style argument.

Although when converting a DataFrame to an image using to_html and HTML, the resulting image may be larger than the Jupyter Notebook cell, which can lead to scrolling. You can avoid this by adjusting the size of the Jupyter Notebook cell or by using a **CSS max-width property** in the styling of the HTML table.

Comment: This looks like it was generated by an AI like ChatGPT, not by a human being. [Posting AI-generated output is officially **banned** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE**.

Answer (score -1):

Transforming a Jupyter Notebook into slides using tools like Jupyter Notebook's built-in slideshow capabilities or external tools like RISE or nbconvert is a great way to present your code and data interactively. However, you may encounter differences in the rendering of DataFrames between the notebook and the slides due to the limitations of the slide format.

Here are some reasons why you might see differences in DataFrame rendering between the notebook and the slides:

1. **Slide format limitations**: Slides typically display content in a linear fashion, one cell at a time. Large DataFrames might not fit neatly onto a slide, leading to truncation or scrolling in the slide view.
2. **Styling and formatting**: Jupyter Notebook allows you to apply various styles and formatting to DataFrames using libraries like Pandas, Styler, or other HTML/CSS techniques. These styles may not carry over to the slide format, resulting in a different appearance.
3. **Cell output settings**: Jupyter Notebook allows you to configure cell outputs interactively, such as displaying only a specific number of rows or columns. These settings might not be preserved in the slide format.
4. **Display functions**: The way DataFrames are displayed in Jupyter Notebook can be influenced by the display functions used (e.g., `df.head()`, `df.tail()`, or simply the last line of a cell). The way cells are executed and displayed in slide mode may affect the choice of display function used, leading to differences.
5. **Screen resolution and sizing**: The size of the slide and the screen resolution can impact how DataFrames are displayed. Smaller slide sizes or lower resolutions may result in less space for displaying data.

To get the same rendering for DataFrames on both the notebook and slides, you can consider the following approaches:

1. **Use smaller DataFrames**: If possible, try to reduce the size of the DataFrames you are displaying on slides. This can help ensure that the data fits neatly on the slides.
2. **Adjust styling**: Ensure that the styling and formatting of DataFrames are not too complex or reliant on specific CSS that may not work well in the slide format. Stick to simple styling that is more likely to translate well to slides.
3. **Set display options**: Use Pandas display options (e.g., `pd.set_option()`) to control the number of rows and columns displayed in DataFrames. This can help ensure that the DataFrames fit well on the slides.
4. **Custom rendering**: Consider custom rendering options, such as creating images or summary statistics of the DataFrame to display on slides. This can be especially useful for large or complex DataFrames.
5. **Interactive elements**: If the interactivity of DataFrames is crucial, you might need to compromise and use a live Jupyter Notebook environment for the presentation, where you can interact with DataFrames as needed.

Ultimately, achieving the exact same rendering on both the notebook and slides may not always be possible due to the differences in their formats and limitations. It's important to strike a balance between displaying the necessary information and making it visually appealing in the presentation format.